# Hailstone Sequence length is off

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm doing a hailstone sequence program that gives out the number with the largest cycle and the length of the cycle. I'm pretty much done except that when i checked the values the length is always off by +1 and i can't seem to figure out why. It is probably something really simple and silly that I'm missing but I would appreciate the help.
Here is my code:

```
def main(): 
  x = int(input("Enter starting number of the range:"))
  y = int(input("Enter ending number of the range:"))
  while (x<1):
    return main()
  while ((y<x) or (y<1)):
    return main()
  z = y +1
  for n in range(x,z):
    max_length = 0 
    length = 0
    seq = [] 
    while n != 1:
      s = (n,seq.append(n))         
      if n % 2 == 0:
         n = n // 2
         length += 1
      else:
          n = (n * 3) + 1
          length += 1
  if n == 1:         
      seq.append(n) 
      length += 1     
  if length > max_length:  
      max_length = length  
      max_seq = seq[:]        

print ("The number", max_seq[0], "has the longest cycle length of", max_length)

main()
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a correct input, output and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code is probably salvagable by someone very dedicated, but it has a lot of problems (not least of which is your chosen indentation of 2 spaces instead of 4). It doesn't run at all as provided, presumably because of the wonky indentation of the `print` statement. This line:

```
s = (n,seq.append(n))
```

assigns a variable `s` which is never used. You alse reset `max_length` for each value of `n` that you test, so you only report the last length you find.

I offer my own solution below:

```
def hailstone(n, ht):
    ht += 1
    if n == 1:
        return 1, ht
    if n % 2:
        return hailstone(3*n+1, ht)
    return hailstone(n/2, ht)

# Change the next line to set limits as appropriate
nmin, nmax = 1,10
max_n, max_len = None, 0
for n in range(nmin, nmax+1):
    ht = 0
    dummy, ht = hailstone(n, ht)
    if ht > max_len:
        max_n, max_len = n, ht
print(max_n,max_len)
```